# How to force HTTPS for all requests Except for a particular directory using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I'm having a heckuva time getting the following to work:

If HTTPS is off, then If the incoming URL is pointing to a specific directory tree (mailbox), leave it alone, Else for all other queries switch to HTTPS.

I've tried several approaches but have boiled it down to what seems like it should be a two line solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule !^/?mailbox/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Seems to set HTTPS for everything but does weird things with the mailbox, such as requesting myhost.com/mailbox/mailbox.php results in https://myhost.com/mailbox.php and a 401 error.

I'm guessing it's a regex problem with trying to use RewriteRule using a negative statement, but not sure.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, was not able to reproduce that behavior with the given information: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=d228847e-a793-42c3-ad44-aabf61178fa9 Are there other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing me to this htaccess tool! My cPanel seems to have some old redirects that aren't reflected in my .htaccess file.  Nothing obviously conflicting, though...

Comment: Interesting that playing with the tool, it won't let me enter a url such as myhost.com/foobar with no http:// preceding it.  That is how my firmware is submitting it, I think?  Other than that it seems to work correctly in the tool.  Huh.  I guess I'll poke around in cPanel to see if it is interfering somehow.

Comment: You really should thing twice before exempting the "mainbox" folder from transport encryption. Assuming that this actually _is_ a mailbox this would mean that exactly that private data is _not_ protected at all, can be freely read by anyone on the network. I doubt that is a good idea.

Comment: I'm not a moron.  This is for my custom designed, solar powered, voice enabled, mailbox sensor with servo activation that lives in the wild.  It reports back whenever mail is delivered to my mailbox, says "thank you very much" to the mailman, throws out a flag, logs it, and texts me that there is mail to pick up.  Its firmware runs on an arduino microcontroller which can't handle https encryption.  So if you can figure out the exact location of this software on my server, you too can see the state of the mail in my physical mailbox down my private driveway!

Comment: There's no good way to have HTTPS for a given hostname for some URL paths and not others. It's kind of a chicken-and-egg problem. How would the client (e.g. browser) know to skip TLS negotiation for a specific URL path? You might be able to do this by having the mailbox be on a different (virtual) hostname on the same IP address, though mixed content warnings might kick in then. Also, since the URL path is encrypted in HTTPS, there's no way for the server to pick HTTP for a specific path until TLS is negotiated and the data is decrypted.

Comment: This questions fits better at [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or possibly serverfault.

Comment: "it won't let me enter a url such as myhost.com/foobar with no http:// preceding it" - It's not an HTTP request unless the URL is prefixed with either `http://` or `https://`, so this part is mandatory. If you don't explicitly include it (such as when typing the URL in the browser) then the UA needs to default to one or the other (which protocol is used depends on browser and settings). Browsers are starting to _default_ to HTTPS (or at least offering this as an option).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the rule in itself, so this suggests "something else" is going on. (A conflict with other directives is a common issue.) Is `/mailbox` a physical filesystem directory? "requesting `myhost.com/mailbox/mailbox.php` results in `https://myhost.com/mailbox.php` and a 401 error" - So, the `/mailbox` path-segment is removed? Via a 3xx redirect? And a "401 Unauthorized" response results (but this is associated with HTTP authentication)? Does `/mailbox.php` (in the root) exist? There is certainly something else doing all of that.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk-Strike "How would the client (e.g. browser) know to skip TLS negotiation for a specific URL path?" - Just use absolute URLs. (?) "though mixed content warnings might kick in" - There would only be "mixed content" if they are genuinely mixing HTTP/HTTPS content on the same page, but this `/mailbox` "service" would seem to be an entirely separate/private service. "there's no way for the server to pick HTTP for a specific path until TLS is neg..." - The OP is not redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP, they are just not redirecting to HTTPS.

Comment: If you remove that one rule, does it work? If so, then you certainly have a conflict with other directives in your `.htaccess` file (or another `.htaccess` file) or the Apache config. _Aside:_ How are you connecting the URL `/mailbox/...` to your custom service? Just a thought... you could keep the entire frontend (including `/mailbox`) as HTTPS, but proxy the requests for your `/mailbox` service using plain HTTP to your backend (avoids the security issues/criticism).